# Website not working with www for domain in hostmonster

Tags: web, dns, hosting

My domain is hosted on hostmonster. It's been there for the past two years and had no problem. Suddenly from yesterday my website stopped working if i use www (i.e) it works if I just type https://mywebsite.com. But if I type in www.mywebsite.com or mywebsite.com or mywebsite and ctrl + enter it doesn't work.

In chrome it shows the error the error code as **ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED**

> The webpage at http://www.mywebsite.com/ might be temporarily down or
>   it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

And in IE it shows **This page can’t be displayed** error.

Yesterday for few hours hostmonster website was down. So I believe it is something wrong going their side. Since their website was down is it something like the dns settings got refreshed and it might take 24-48 hours for the dns to work properly? Or is it something I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is with them. People are complaining on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/hostmonster/with_replies) for the same thing.

This is *the* worst day out of the year for my sites to be down!